# Automated variable naming in R

Tags: r, automation

I am attempting to automate some tests in R, but want to be able to access the results like so: `example$test1.param1`. Currently, the values will run the tests but I have no way of assigning the result to the correct name.

```
x <- c("test1", "test2", "test3")
y <- c("param1", "param2", "param3")

i <- 1
j <- 1
for (foo in x) {
  for (bar in y) {
    print(c(foo, bar))
    j <- j +1
  }
  i <- i +1
}
```

which yields:

```
[1] "test1"  "param1"
[1] "test1"  "param2"
[1] "test1"  "param3"
[1] "test2"  "param1"
[1] "test2"  "param2"
[1] "test2"  "param3"
[1] "test3"  "param1"
[1] "test3"  "param2"
[1] "test3"  "param3"
```

I attempted to create a list and redirect the output there, but I do not know how to get the `$test1.param1` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not exactly sure whether you are going the right way but you can use named lists:

```
x <- c("test1", "test2", "test3")
y <- c("param1", "param2", "param3")

i <- 1
j <- 1
mylist <- list()
for (foo in x) {
  for (bar in y) {
    print(c(foo, bar))
    mylist[[paste(foo, bar, sep = ".")]] <- c(foo, bar)
    j <- j +1
  }
  i <- i + 1
}

mylist$test1.param1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the code below is what your are after. Assuming `example` is your unnamed list, then you can try the following to assign the names

```
example <- setNames(example,c(t(outer(x,y,paste,sep = "."))))
```

where

```
> c(t(outer(x,y,paste,sep = ".")))
[1] "test1.param1" "test1.param2" "test1.param3" "test2.param1" "test2.param2" "test2.param3"
[7] "test3.param1" "test3.param2" "test3.param3"
```